# R: How could I change this loop to apply?

Tags: r, loops

I'm currently working on an R program, where there is one part of this program that computes in a loop two values which are interdependant. Although since I have to do 100,000 iterations it takes so long time.

So I would like to substitute this for loop for an apply loop or some more efficient function, but I don't know how to do it. Could someone help me?

```
p <- c()
for(i in 1:n) {
  if(i == 1) {
   x <- b[i]
  }
  else {
    x <- c(x, max(h[i - 1], p[i]))
  }
  h <- c(h, x[i] + y[i])
}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What assigns values to `p`? Are the `h`s supposed to be `p`s?

Comment: Your question above is not very clear what is x, y, p, b and h?  One piece of advice:  It is time consuming to continuously append to a vector with the x<-c(x, addnewvalue) notation.  Preallocate x<-vector(n) and then assign values with x[i]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to have a full working example here, but the main problem is that building up the `x` and `h` vectors with the `c()` function is very slow.  It's better to preallocate them:

```
x <- numeric(n)  # allocate vector of size n
h <- numeric(n)
```

and then fill them in as you go by assigning to `x[i]` and `h[i]`.  For example, the following loop:

```
x <- c(); for (i in 1:100000) x <- c(x,1)
```

takes about 10 seconds to run on my laptop, but this version:

```
x <- numeric(100000); for (i in 1:100000) x[i] <- 1
```

does the same thing while running almost instantly.